# What do you do with 5 VDC at 150 amps?

Tags: switch-mode-power-supply, switching, industrial

I recently picked up a switching power supply that is rated for 5 VDC at 150 A wondering in industry where you might find that being used. I was told possibly older industrial computers still running TTL but I'm wonder where else thank you.

Comment: I don't really get how this question is opinion-based. Wouldn't a hypothetical answer containing example(s) of applications demanding the stated specs be entirely factual?

Comment: A factual answer does not necessarily become a good answer on this occasion.

Comment: @Andyaka The question is clearly stated (even if in imperfect English), specific, and the subject matter is applicable to the site. Factual answers are conceivable. Isn't that enough? Voters can judge whether an answer is "good."

Comment: @TypeIA **NO** a factual answer is **NOT ENOUGH** if the question is asking for opinions. How can the best answer be selected if all the given answers are equally good but based on opinions. Questions like this weaken the site and get stamped on.

Comment: "Some subjective questions are allowed, but “subjective” does not mean “anything goes”. All subjective questions are expected to be constructive. What does that mean? Constructive subjective questions: insist that opinion be backed up with facts and references" https://electronics.stackexchange.com/help/dont-ask

Comment: Even if it weren't off-topic on the grounds that answers would be opinion-based, it would be off-topic as it concerns the use of electronic devices.

Comment: I think the overbearing topic of all stackexchange sites is "questions which can have correct answers, from which you could accept the best". There's no best answer to select, and honestly, this question's answer is basically limited to one's imagination. Heat up water to produce vapor pressure to shoot large model rockets? Sure, why not.

Comment: A friend is uses 4 of these to charge individual cells in a 4s high capacity LiFePO4 battery. Each output is isolated allowing each cell to be correctly charged with relatively simple circuitry. This allows "perfectly" matched voltage top balancing in minimum time. || An electrolytic cell: water cells run at about 1.25 V. Al pots operate  at about 4.5 - 5.5 V. | Some LED systems could operate from 5V or electronics with 5V or lower supplies. | I bought about 100 such supplies from a defunct LED billboard company. Exact use unknown but "smart" LEDs and associated electronics probably